# Fit TitleWindow to contents

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

If I don't specify width and height values for a `TitleWindow`, it will be resized to fit it's contents when I show it using `PopUpManager`.

But there are moments when some components inside will be resized, like a `ComboBox` which `dataProvider` is loaded asynchronously, or another component which was not visible and I'd like to set it's `includeInLayout` to `true`.

In those moments, I'd like to tell the TitleWindow to resize itself to fit window contents. I've tried calling `invalidateSize()` and `invalidateDisplayList()` with no success.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call these two methods:

```
titleWindow.invalidateSize();
titleWindow.validateNow(); // or titleWindow.validateSize()
```

Comment: Now it worked: I had a ViewStack inside the titleWindow, so I had to set it's percentWidth to NaN and resizeToContent=true before calling invalidateSize(). Also, I had to set percentWidth to NaN in the conainers inside that ViewStack. After that, the TitleWindow started measuring properly. Thanks!

Just a quick reminder if anyone else has this issue: don't forget to set explicitWidth/explicitHeight of the TitleWindow to NaN so that it will adjust itself to it's contents.